# SQL - how to include average of a column in a report

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here's the scenario:

I have an Access project with tables consisting of the following data:

```
Activity table: ActivityName, ActivityPopularityRating
Volunteer table: VolunteerName, VolunteerRating
```

Each activity can have many volunteers and each volunteer has a rating.

I have to create a report which indicates for each activity, the names and ratings of the volunteers taking part in that activity, as well as the average VolunteerRating of the those volunteers taking part in each activity. An example is attached.

I have created the SQL query but I am not sure if I should generate the average value needed in the query, or if there is some function in Access that would allow me to do that in the report.

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT Activity.ActivityName,
       Activity.ActivityPopularityRating, 
       StudentVolunteer.VolunteerName,
       StudentVolunteer.VolunteerRating, 
       AVG(StudentVolunteer.VolunteerRating)
FROM Activity
  INNER JOIN StudentVolunteer ON Activity.ActivityName = StudentVolunteer.ActivityName
GROUP BY Activity.ActivityName
```

All help is appreciated

Thanks

[image: Report Example]

Comment: If you have an "Access" project, then you should tag the question appropriately.  I removed the MySQL tag and added the appropriate tags.  Because your question is also about reporting, you should tag it with the application software you are using.

Comment: Remove the Avg() in the above SQL, then use [DAvg](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/davg.php), on the Query.

Comment: The general group by rule is: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: @jarlh Thank you for editing my query, however now the error which i receive is "ActivityPopularityRating is not part of an aggregate function".

Answer (score 0):

To add a total line (here showing the average rating) to your results, you would use UNION ALL in MsAccess (or ROLLUP in another DBMS). However, it is not necessary to add such line to your query. The data is already there (it is the avarage of the selected ratings, which can easily be calcualted from them).

So remove GROUP BY and the AVG line from your query and add AVG(VolunteerRating) in your report layer instead. The *report* will then calculate the avarage from the ratings.